# Is there a way to map Func<T1, bool> to Func<T2, bool>?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-expressions

So, I was wondering if it possible to do the next thing in c#:

I have a DB model - let's say it is `Car`:

```
public class Car {
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set}
}
```

And a DbSet for this type in `someDbContext`:

```
public DbSet<Car> Cars {get;set;}
```

And also I have a `CarDto`

```
public class CarDto {
  public string Id {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set}
}
```

And as result we get something like this:

```
var select = new Func<CarDto, bool>(car => car.Name == "BMW");

// And somehow use this expression for other type Car
someDbContext.Cars.Where(select);
```

Maybe there is an approach in which I could map these `Funcs` like this:

```
var newFunc = mapper.Map<Func<Car, bool>>(select);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Presumably you're talking about `Expression<Func<Whatever, bool>>` not `Func<Whatever, bool>`?

Comment: Doing the mapping is a bit fiddly, even with expressions: you need to replace every access to a member of the first objected with the access to the corresponding member on the new object. It's easier to build both from the ground up, which is what my answer does

Comment: @canton7 I want to build different queries, (if it is possible) not just with one parameter. `x => x.Name == "bla bla" && x.Id != "bla bla"` for example.

Comment: Are you just accessing properties, or also calling methods / operators / etc?

Comment: @canton7 only properties as the objects I would pass are simply data models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to handle rewriting property accesses, you can use an `ExpressionVisitor` which looks a bit like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression<Func<Car, bool>> expr = x => x.Name == "BMW";
        var replaced = ReplaceParameter<CarDto>(expr);
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ReplaceParameter<T>(LambdaExpression expr)
    {
        if (expr.Parameters.Count != 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("Expected 1 parameter", nameof(expr));

        var newParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), expr.Parameters[0].Name);
        var visitor = new ParameterReplaceVisitor()
        {
            Target = expr.Parameters[0],
            Replacement = newParameter,
        };
        var rewrittenBody = visitor.Visit(expr.Body);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(rewrittenBody, newParameter);
    }
}

public class ParameterReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression Target { get; set; }
    public ParameterExpression Replacement { get; set; }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Expression == this.Target)
        {
            // Try and find a property with the same name on the target type
            var members = this.Replacement.Type.GetMember(node.Member.Name, node.Member.MemberType, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (members.Length != 1)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Unable to find a single member {node.Member.Name} of type {node.Member.MemberType} on {this.Target.Type}");
            }
            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(this.Replacement, members[0]);
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

We need to deconstruct the `LambdaExpression` into its body and parameters. We need to create a new parameter which has the correct type, and replace all usages of the old parameter with the new one. This is where the visitor comes in: whenever it sees you access a member on the old parameter, it tries to find the corresponding member on the new parameter, and access that instead.

We then construct a new `LambdaExpression`, using the rewritten body and the new parameter.

Comment: But this approach will work only  for `car` type that includes `Name` property.

Comment: It would be great to map `Func<CarDto, bool>` to `Func<Car, bool>` and then use it inside the linq query

Comment: @Batuhan Indeed. Modifying that is left as an exercise to the reader :)

Comment: @LabLab Obviously if you have a collection of `Car` objects, you need to filter that using an `Expression<Func<Car, bool>>` and not an `Expression<Func<AnythingElse,bool>>`. In interpreted your question as asking how to construct predicates for different object types -- if that's not your question, please clarify it!

Comment: @canton7 sorry, my bad. Question was edited

Comment: (Answer completely rewritten; earlier comments no longer applicable)

Answer (score 2):

You have a whole bunch of options:

1. Derive your Dto class from the context class. That way you can use polymorphism as normal.
2. Extract an interface and implement it in both your Dto and context classes. Same as above then, use polymorphism.
3. Use duck-typing. In C#, that's done with the `dynamic` keyword. You lose Intellisense and compile-time error checking, but your code will work.
4. Reflection. It's a lot of code, it's slow, it's practically a much worse version of #3, but you can cobble it together if you really try.

Something like Automapper will help you map your context to your Dto piece-wise, but it won't help you translate your lambda function filters.

Comment: Is deriving Dto from context a good practice at all?

Comment: Depends on your specific classes and how closely related they are. In your example, absolutely, you can practically use the same classes.

Comment: It was a simple example to briefly explain my question. In fact I use more complicated entities with a lot of links to other entities and etc

Comment: As I said, it depends. Personally, I would (and have) used the `dynamic` version. Duck typing is very powerful.